# Why can't I specialize a template with an alias template in the return type in MSVC?

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, language-lawyer, compiler-bug

MSVC refuses to compile this:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct G { void operator()() const { } };

template<class T>
using MyTrait = std::is_void<T>;

struct S
{
    template<class F>
    std::enable_if_t<MyTrait<decltype(std::declval<F>()())>::value> run(F &&);
};
template<>
void S::run(G &&);
```

with the error:

```
<source>(14): error C2910: 'S::run': cannot be explicitly specialized
<source>(16): error C2760: syntax error: 'int' was unexpected here; expected ';'
```

But Clang and GCC compile it just fine. And they all compile it fine if I say `std::is_void` instead of `MyTrait`.

Why is this? Is it a compiler bug, or is there something in the language that causes this problem?

Comment: hmm.. there is slight issue that argument of `run` is a forwarding reference. You specialize it as a rvalue reference, is that intended? Cannot reproduce this, which version of MSVC  reports an error? `/std:c++17` takes care of it for mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a compiler bug. Defining explicit specializations of member function templates is perfectly legal.

`std::enable_if_t<MyTrait<decltype(std::declval<F>()())>::value>` is ultimately an alias for `void` with SFINAE, and the use of aliases shouldn't prevent specialization.

> In a declaration whose *declarator-id* refers to a specialization of a function template, template argument deduction is performed to identify the specialization to which the declaration refers.
> Specifically, this is done for explicit instantiations, **explicit specializations**, and certain friend declarations.

- [[temp.deduc.decl] p1](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.decl#1)

The process to determine whether the full specialization `void S::run(G&&)` matches the member function template is the same as if you had called `S::run(g)` where `g` is an argument of type `G`.

During this process, `std::enable_if_t<MyTrait<decltype(std::declval<F>()())>::value>` where `F = G` would turn into `void`.

It's worth noting that your example does compile with:

```cpp
template<class F>
std::enable_if_t<MyTrait<decltype(G{}())>::value> run(F&&);
```

... which is pretty much the same thing, and MSVC is being inconsistent here.

#### Note on MSVC versions

[MSVC 19.35 compiles this](https://godbolt.org/z/fGxjqv5fY), but [more recent versions raise an error](https://godbolt.org/z/GM1e86e31). I was unable to find a bug report for this issue, perhaps because it is relatively recent and no one has noticed/reported it yet.

#### Bug report

I've submitted [a bug report](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Spurious-error-C2910-when-defining-expli/10462963?q=%22explicit+specialization%22+%22member%22+C2910) for this issue.

Comment: Much appreciation for submitting the bug report to Microsoft! I think it's also worth noting that another workaround for this problem is to derive from the type-trait instead of aliasing it, as in: `template<typename T>
struct MyTrait : std::is_void<T> {};`